# Facebook share not working

Tags: facebook, share

Have this problem, I have a WordPress website and on the `single.php` file when articles are we have a scrolling social bar, with Facebook like, Tweeter and Google+

However I wanted to change the Facebook like into a Facebook share button.

Anyone have the answer to this, I've been searching for ages to find a solution.

The Facebook like code I have is:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=100&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:20px;">
</iframe>
```

I have tried using: `<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-type="box_count"></div>`.

This doesn't display all the time in Firefox and is virtually non-existent in Chrome, Safari and IE.

I use Facebook comments, so when share button doesn't appear, nor does the comments section.

I'm at my witts end with it.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `data-href="perma-link stuff"` that Facebook automatically puts in for you.